# adjust output with input field and add/minus button AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

it is my first time to use angularjs
i am trying to make a sample code wherein the user can put a number on the field or he can use the button to increase/ decrease the number but not less than 0.

```
  <div data-ng-app='CountApp' data-ng-controller='CountCtrl'>
  <div class="outside-border">
    <input id="output_test" type="text" ng-model="count" style="width: 150px;">
    <div class="minus">
      <button class="button" id="test_sample" data-ng-click='count = count - 1'>-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="add">
      <button class="button" data-ng-click='count = count + 1'>+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



var app = angular.module('CountApp', []);

app.controller('CountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 1;
});
```

Currently what is happening is that whenever there is no number on the field and user click  + button, the output is 1111111
or if the user enter a number (e.g. 35) the output becomes 3511111
can someone explain or help me with regards to this.

here is what i have done so far https://jsfiddle.net/wbuh2hrd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ternary operation to validate the count is less than 0 or not like this

```
 <button class="button" id="test_sample" data-ng-click='count = (count <= 0) ? 0 : count-1' >-</button>
```

and add function to plus button and cast the string to int

```
<button class="button" data-ng-click='plusCount()'>+</button>
$scope.plusCount = function(){
  $scope.count = parseInt($scope.count) + 1;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kq40rrqq/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this, one of them is changing your input type to `type="number"`

If you don't like the buttons that appears when you mouseover on certain browsers, you can hide it using css (http://www.thatstevensguy.com/programming/disable-arrows-on-number-inputs/)

Edit: You can use `min=0` to control minimum value in number type input.